# How to create TextView with cross(x) button at end of it?

Tags: textview, android

Is there any widget like TextView which contains a cross button, or is there any property for TextView by which it is created automatically? I want the cross button to delete whatever text written in TextView.Here is snap shot of what I want.

[image]

Fisrt image is selected textview and second which I want to delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library for your need. It has cool buttons and much more.

Check out [the library](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap)

How to use it :-

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Success"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
/>
```